# Highcharts change prototype function based on options

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to change the function of Highcharts.

```
H.Pointer.prototype.reset
```

Here is my example:

```
var orignalReset = H.Pointer.prototype.reset;

H.Pointer.prototype.reset = function (e) {
  if(this.options.tooltip.syncronized){
    return undefined;
  }else{
    orignalReset();
  }
};
```

Problem: By this method I am not able to  pass `this` reference. 
Assigning to a variable has lost the connection to the original method/class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap it, as described in "[Extending highcharts](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)".

I'm not sure what `tooltip.syncronized` is, so I've made an example with `tooltip.shared`. For example, you could wrap the `Pointer.reset` function to not do anything if the tooltip is shared, and otherwise do the normal thing, like this:

```
(function (H) {
  H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'reset', function (proceed, allowMove, delay) {
    if(this.chart.options.tooltip.shared) {
        console.log('shared: not doing anything.');
    }
    else {
      console.log('not shared: normal behavior.');
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    }
  });
}(Highcharts));
```

See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/kf3spb0t/) of it in action on two separate Highcharts.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks.